# Rules - Check if coupon has been added to an order

Tags: commerce, rules

I need to check in Rules if a coupon has been added to an order as a condition.

I have tried using the ENTITY HAS FIELD option in Rules and then a data selector of

Commerce-order

and to then look for the field commerce_coupon_code

But this fires a negative, I have also tried to look for commerce_coupon_fixed_amount

But this also fires a negative.

Answer (score 0):

Add A Condition Also In Rules That Will Help You In These You Can Also Create Manual Option